# Does spring-boot requires Maven or Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot

My questions is:  Can spring-boot application be created without Maven or Gradle support by keeping required jar files in classpath?

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically possible, but manually collecting the *correct versions* of the required JAR files seems impractical. In fact, one of the goal of Spring Boot is to maintain a list of *spring-boot-starters*, so that you can just use those in your build configuration file (like pom.xml), and the *correct version* of all the dependency JARs will be pulled into your classpath.

Comment: I absolutely agree on this point. Trying to manage all the dependencies in the correct version simply doesn't make sense. Moreover, you would lose one of the main advantages of spring-boot: having a ll the dependencies together with the correct version defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you have your own build system you can certainly gather all of the jars yourself and include them.  Maven and Gradle both make it easier to get all of those jars and include tools for building the runnable jar file.